# Syntax: How can this tree be built?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

I am working through "Contemporary Linguistics" on my own.  It's been going pretty well, but I have a question about building syntax trees.

I understand the tree here for "The dog might bite that man" fairly well. Now, I would like to add "tomorrow" to the end of the sentence.  I've looked through the book, and the only similar example I can find is using "never", which comes in front of the verb.

Is this there a Move happening here?

> Tomorrow the dog might bite that man.

This is correct grammar, but I don't see anything to attach *tomorrow* to on the left side of the sentence.

> *The dog might tomorrow bite that man.

This is not correct grammar, and I believe that means tomorrow could not have moved from there?

I don't quite know if "The dog tomorrow might bite that man" is correct grammar, but it seems much less ungrammatical than *"tomorrow bite".  Could the adverb attach to the I?

How can I build this tree?

[image: A syntax tree for "The dog might bite the man."]

Comment: "tomorrow" is an adjunct. By the way, are you aware of this website? http://bcs.bedfordstmartins.com/linguistics6e/default.asp?s=&n=&i=&v=&o=&ns=0&uid=0&rau=0

Comment: See also this [freshman grammar problem](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Niching.pdf), where the simplest answer has to do with identifying constituents (never mind the labels; labels get changed regularly).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help with particular syntax trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tomorrow` simply becomes a part of a Verbal Phrase (VP):

**update 2**

```
I'
. I: might
. VP
. . VP
. . . V: bite
. . . NP
. . . . DET: that
. . . . N: man
. . PP
. . . Adv: tomorrow
```

Also, note that there are two possible formal representations:

1. `bite tomorrow`, as pictured above;
2. `might tomorrow`, when `tomorrow` becomes a part of epistemic modality verb phrase (`I'` in your diagram);

I guess the clash may be caused by mixing **language-specific** and **language-agnostic** semantic graphs.
The former are often vulnerable to artifacts that prevent displaying them into a nice tree-style structure. Maybe the simplest example would be separable prefixes in German language:

> Ich **fange** mit der Arbeit **an** ("I begin with studying")

Here, VP is `mit der Arbeit`, but the V itself splits into two words around its VP, which can't be represented with a nice tree. In a language-agnostic semantic graph, there is no such problem.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to read your "tomorrow" N-NP-PP?

Comment: that HPSG parser might not give the same kind of trees as the transformationalist textbook the OP is working with.

Comment: Why is "tomorrow" Adj?

Comment: Thanks bytebuster.  I've tried to recreate the tree you made.  Does this look right? http://i.imgur.com/CUmed.jpg  If that looks good I will accept this.  If I changed this to "might bite tomorrow" would the NP just drop out, keeping the two VPs?  Thanks!

Comment: @arsenius Yes, if it matches the required notation (which I'm not familiar with, otherwise my answer worked from the first try).

Comment: Well, as I'm a beginner at this I'm not in a position to say that it *doesn't* match! I'll accept this. Thanks!

Comment: @arsenius, your tree structure is wrong! 1. tomorrow is AdvP; in fact, how can it change it category? You start with tomorrow-Adv and then it becomes PP? 2. You can't have V' above VP. You can repeat layers, like V'-V'-VP or V'-VP-VP etc. but the bar projection is always below the phrasal projection. Let's see what jlawler will say.

Comment: @jlawler, what do you think of this tree? http://i.imgur.com/CUmed.jpg I think it's wrong (see above).

Comment: @AlexB. `tomorrow`, and Adverb, belongs to a Prepositional Phrase in exactly the same way as `that man`, a Noun, belongs to a **Verb** Phrase, isn't it?

Comment: @bytebuster, but where is the head of your PP in this sentence - I don't see any preposition here.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. If you propose a PP, then it must have a head, P. What is P in your proposal? What is it expressed by?

Comment: Although I can't really add anything here, I just wanted to mention that I am still following this conversation and finding it quite instructive.  Thank you AlexB and bytebuster.

Comment: Do you have a real picture of what will the tree look like?